# getting friend friend list with koala

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, friend, koala

As mentioned, for example, my name is Nicholas, I have 200 friends, and I'm able to get a list of my friends with no problem. Now I want to choose one of my friends and retrieve their friends list, I'm using

```
get_connection(friend_name , "friends")
```

my controller is

```
get_friend_friennd_list(friend_name)
```

and in my view

```
get_friend_friend_list_path(friend['name'])
```

however, it gives me an error, anyone know how to do it? Any hints?

Comment: Please provide more information, what have you tried, what is the error you are receiving, and what have you done? Have you instantiated a graph object with the required OAuth token?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get friends of a friend on Facebook.  If you try, Facebook will give you an error:

"(#604) Can't lookup all friends of XXXX. Can only lookup for the logged in user or the logged in user's friends that are users of your app.",

Comment: oic..thanks for your quick reply..because i able to check my friend 'friend list ,so i think it is possible to retrieve them as well..do you know how to pass a controller function with parameter ,then used it in my view? like get_friend(friend_name)